# Estimating heteroscedastic variance using a log transform

Tags: variance, estimation, heteroscedasticity

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4178) I read, they are using a NN to estimate the heteroscedastic variance in a regression scenario (actually a bit more complicated than this, but irrelevant to the question). After they fit 1 NN for the mean, they use another NN $g_{w'}$ optimized by the squared error loss (with weights, and regularization):

$$  w'^* = \arg\min_{w'} \sum_i [\log(\theta_i-\hat \mu(x_{i,sim}))^2-g_{w'}(x_{i,sim})]^2 K_{\epsilon}(||x_{obs}-x_{i,sim}||) + \lambda ||w'||_2
$$

The optimal weights of this NN then supposedly (according to the paper) output the estimated variance:

$$\hat\sigma^2 (x)= \exp{(g_{w'}^*(x))}
$$

I tried testing this without the regression (i.e., a regular sample), and without weights or regularization. The optimal solution of a sum of squared-errors loss would then be the mean $g^* = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \log(\theta_i-\mu_\theta)^2$. However the results I get is that

$$\sigma^2 \approx 4 \exp{(g^*)}
$$

I'm not sure where that 4 is coming from...

Code:

```
n = 50000
x = rnorm(n, mean=200, sd=15)
z = log((x-mean(x))^2)
2*sqrt(exp(mean(z))) # should be ~ sd
```

Here's another example using Linear regression for the mean, and loess for the variance - here too there's seems to be some multiplying coefficient in the vicinity of 4:

```
# Regression example
set.seed(247)
x = seq(-pi,pi,0.01)
n = length(x)
sigmas = 0.75*abs(sin(x))+0.1  # non linear structure for the variance
plot(x, sigmas, type='l')

a = -1
b = 0.7
lp = a + b*x
plot(x, lp, type='l')

y = lp + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=sigmas)
plot(x,y)

fit = lm(y~x)
lines(x, predict(fit), col=2)

z = log((y-predict(fit))^2)  # transform the residuals to be unconstrained
plot(x, z)

loess50 = loess(z ~ x, span=.5)  # fit the residuals using some non-linear fit
lines(x,predict(loess50), col=2)

plot(x,4*exp(predict(loess50)),col=1, type='l') # why the 4???
lines(x,(sigmas^2),col=2)
```

[image]

Also if we make the variance structure linear the ~4 multiplier appears, e.g.:

```
...
sigmas = 0.5+0.1*x
...
fit.sigmas = lm(z~x)
...
plot(x,4*exp(predict(fit.sigmas)),col=1, type='l')
lines(x,(sigmas^2),col=2)
```

[image]